# Normals on human bake displaying incorrectly

Tags: modeling, shaders

I have a 400k TRI human which has been remeshed to a 50k TRI low poly human.

I have baked both the diffuse and the normal maps onto the low poly human. However, the normals do not appear to be displaying correctly on the low poly.

The `.blend` file is available for download here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWoylzP5XP5UDpWcqBmFX8DC4-niLnet/view?usp=sharing

What is wrong with my model?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See your current normal map, it has incorrect colors that are out of the spectrum of a good normal map:

[image]

Actually the bake went bad because the surface of the high-poly is going through the surface of the low-poly:

[image]

In that case you need to give a bit of *Extrusion* to the bake, like 0.1, it means that you want the rays to start a bit away from the low-poly surface in order to be able to catch the high-poly surface:

[image]

Here is the result, not perfect because the ray still hits inverted normals but you can correct with a bit of painting if it causes artefacts:

[image]

Here is how baking works (blue arrows are the normals of the mesh, dotted arrows are the baking rays, h is for high-poly, l is for low-poly):

[image]

If the surface of the high-poly goes beyond the surface of the low-poly, the rays will miss these faces and will hit the inverted faces that are further inside the mesh, therefore the bad colors:

[image]

If you give a bit of *Extrusion* to the bake, you ask Blender to start the rays above the low-poly surface, this time it will be able to catch these surfaces:

[image]