# Normal Map has yellow artifacts after baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Hello I am new to blender and trying to create a cave for a game using Blender. When I create a normal map, there are yellow artifacts on it. I have flipped the normals because I want the cave to be seen from the inside. Does anyone have an idea how I can avoid these yellow artifacts?
Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the file to have a look?

Comment: it's mean that the bake is bad, maybe read my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261669/normals-on-human-bake-displaying-incorrectly

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Sqx2VKeA/ Here is the link for the blender file. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the detailed answer did not help me, because there is only one object in my scene. This caused the error message "No valid selected objects".

Comment: If anyone has the same problem: This post (https://blenderartists.org/t/unwrap-a-cave/1177587) has helped me a lot